# How to get the active tab index in Ionic 2?

Tags: tabs, ionic2

Is there any way to get the active tab index in Ionic 2? I have searched, in Ionic 1 there is $ionicTabsDelegate.

Answer (score 11):

Pass the event object to your method:

```
<ion-tabs (ionChange)="tabSelected($event)">
```

The event object is actually the selected `Tab`:

```
tabSelected(tab: Tab) {
  console.log(tab.index);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the index in the event object, but it works when I use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your navController should link to the nested Tab which has a property 'index'.

`console.log((<Tab>this.navCtrl).index);`

I think this is a little hacky so I'm happy to see other answers. But for the moment you could try that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID to the `tabs` element e.g. `<ion-tabs #myTabs>` and use `@ViewChild('myTabs') myTabs: Tabs;` to get a reference to the HTML `tabs` element. In the controller you can call `this.myTabs.getSelected()` which has an `index` property, which return the active tab's index